# Flask Azure web app deployed successfully but showing default page

Tags: python, azure, flask, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I deployed a python flask app with azure web service using local git. The status in the deployment center shows "success" but when i go to the web page, it is still the default page that tells me I'm running python 3.6.6.

When i navigate to the kudu git clone uri it says " no route registered for '/testapp1.git'

The /wwwroot folder in kudu also has the following files.

```
env
static (css folder)
__pycache__
app.py
hostingstart-python.html
hostingstart-python.py
index.html
requirements.txt
web.config
```

A potential problem could be because the web.config file is still refering to the hostingstart-python.application.

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key ="pythonpath" value="%systemDrive%home\site\wwwroot" />
      <add key ="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hostingstart-python.application" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I tried to follow the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python but this is for linux so i'm not sure what to do as i'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my work steps and see if the error still shows up.:

As you found in the [Managing Python on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service) , Azure App Service provide you with a `site extension`. You could install packages on `KUDU console`.

Step 1 : Create azure web app and add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.4 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via e.g: `python -m pip install Flask`

[image]

BTW,you could remove the default homepage.