# How do I deploy a python app from git to an azure app?

Tags: git, azure, flask

i am a beginner in Azure, but followed a tutorial. I created an Azure App Service and connected it to the Github with a **requirements.txt** and **main.py** file. The py-file is a simple **Flask** web api.

In Azure I used the "**Deployment Center**" to configure the link to git and everything runs sucessfully according to the logs. The Issue is, that the app is still the default app and not my App from my git repo.

Is there something I am missing? Do I need to trigger a refresh somewhere or do I need to run the **py**-file somehow? I tried to restart the Azure App Service, but this didnt help.

The Web App in Azure is in Linux with Python 3.8

I checked with FileZilla and all files from my git are in the **wwwroot** folder. Gut they seem to be ignored not executed. Do I need to trigger the Flask App manually somehow?

Comment: is this a linux or weindows app

Comment: The Web App in Azure is in Linux with Python 3.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137042/flask-azure-web-app-deployed-successfully-but-showing-default-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that Azure App Service doesn't know that `main.py` is the entry module for your application. Rename it to `app.py`. If you still encounter issues, try to deploy [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world) sample Flask application just to see if something else went wrong (I was just able to successfully deploy it to an Azure App Service with runtime stack Python 3.8)